# FTDI USB hub continuously disconnects/reconnects, endlessly

Tags: kernel, usb

I have machine that continuously drops and reloads the FTDI FT4232H. I have tried replacing the cables, still happens.

I've tried to set `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` in the kernel boot params, thinking that might be a autosuspend issue, but it still happens.

Full logs: http://termbin.com/0na9

Some logs:

```
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:44 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 54 using xhci_hcd
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 54
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:45 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 55 using xhci_hcd
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 55
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 56 using xhci_hcd
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 56
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:02:46 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:02:47 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 57 using xhci_hcd
Aug 22 17:02:47 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
Aug 22 17:02:47 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Device not responding to setup address.
Aug 22 17:02:47 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: device not accepting address 57, error -71
Aug 22 17:02:48 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb usb1-port8: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
Aug 22 17:02:48 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb usb1-port8: attempt power cycle
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:02:49 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 59
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: Detected FT4232H
Aug 22 17:03:27 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 60
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.0: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.1: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.2: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: ftdi_sio 1-8:1.3: device disconnected
Aug 22 17:03:29 evo4k-098acd kernel: usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
```

My machine/kernel:

```
Linux evo4k-098acd 4.14.48-intel-pk-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 2 15:53:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Super long shot, but did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue with the same FTDI chip.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using all manner of micro controller development boards for a long time now and have found connecting USB Serial adapters via USB 3 ports or external USB hubs can have issues like this, I've always had the most success using USB 2 ports without an external USB hub.